# Erasing a randomly generated number but comparing user input to that number after its removed from screen

Tags: bash

I have to Write a bash script to generate a 10 digit random number. Then I have to "erase" the number after x seconds. Then have the user try to remember the number and type in what they saw and compare the two giving back a yes or no

here is my random number

```
echo $RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM | cut -c3-12
```

and I made a line that erases after 5 seconds but it erases the line its counting on instead of my random number line

```
for i in {1..5};do echo $i;sleep 1;tput cuu1;tput el;done
```

So I run

```
echo $RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM | cut -c3-12
for i in {1..5};do echo $i;sleep 1;tput cuu1;tput el;done
```

and it counts up to 5 on a line below the random number then deletes the line it was counting on. How do I erase the random number and still store it to compare user input to?

Comment: well, you're just echoing out the random number. why not ``num=`$rand$rand$rand|cut etc...` ``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the random number in a variable. Erase the random number after the loop using the same commands you used inside the loop:

```
random_number=$(cut -c3-12 <<< $RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM)
echo $random_number 

for i in {1..5}
do
   echo $i
   sleep 1
   tput cuu1
   tput el
done

tput cuu1
tput el
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `tput cuu1;tput el` after your `for` loop, so your code looks like:

```
echo $RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM | cut -c3-12
for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; sleep 1; tput cuu1; tput el; done
tput cuu1; tput el
```

Comment: ok I see, so that just clears 1 more line again right after the timer runs?

Comment: @user3485895: Yes. `tput cuu1` moves cursor one line up, and `tput el` erases line. So after you echo your last number (the cursor is line below) you do "line up, line erase" just before you leave `for` loop and then again "line up, line erase", which erases you random number.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little memory game similar to this in bash. It is quite old and ugly but maybe it will help you out a bit.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

banner="=============================================="

echo ""
echo -e "\x1b[93m Yokai's Guessing game! \x1b[0m"
echo "$banner"
echo ""
echo "I will give you a number and you will have 10 seconds to remember it."
echo "After 10 seconds it will disappear and you will have to try to guess it."
echo ""
read -p "Press <enter> to continue"

main() {
clear

GEN="$(tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 10)"

echo ""
echo -e "\x1b[93m Yokai's Guessing game! \x1b[0m"
echo "$banner"
echo ""
echo -e "Your number is:\x1b[31m $GEN \x1b[0m"
sleep 10
clear

echo ""
echo -e "\x1b[93m Yokai's Guessing game! \x1b[0m"
echo "$banner"
echo ""
echo "Can you remember the number?"
echo ""
read GUESS

if [ "$GUESS" == "$GEN" ]
then
clear
echo ""
echo -e "\x1b[93m Yokai's Guessing game! \x1b[0m"
echo "$banner"
echo ""
echo "You guessed correctly!! Well done!!"
sleep 2
echo "Would you like to play again?"
echo "(y/n)"
echo ""
read ANSWER

until [ "$ANSWER" == "y" ]
do
echo ""
echo "Okay, thanks for playing!"
sleep 2
clear
exit 0
done
fi

if [ "$GUESS" != "$GEN" ]
then
clear
echo ""
echo -e "\x1b[93m Yokai's Guessing game! \x1b[0m"
echo "$banner"
echo ""
echo "Oooooooh! Sorry but that number was incorrect!"
echo "Would you like to try again?"
echo "(y/n)"
read CHOICE

if [ "$CHOICE" == "n" ]
then
clear
echo ""
echo -e "\x1b[93m Yokai's Guessing game! \x1b[0m"
echo "$banner"
echo ""
echo "Okay thanks for playing!"
sleep 2
clear
exit 0
fi
fi


}

while true
do
main
done
```